# User-Defined Extended Enums in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums, user-defined

I am writing a TypeScript library that uses enums, like this:

```
export enum Fruit {
  // enum values must be integers,
  // because the upstream library expects them that way.
  Apple = 0,
  Banana = 1,
}

/** A wrapper function for `upstreamLibrary.useFruit`. */
export function useFruit(fruit: Fruit) {
  upstreamLibrary.useFruit(fruit as number);
  // TODO: Do more stuff.
}
```

By default, the library ships with Apples and Bananas, but I want end-users to be able to create their own fruit. Right now, they can do that like the following:

```
import { useFruit } from "fruits";

enum FruitCustom {
  // `upstreamLibrary.getFruitValue` returns an integer.
  // It is guaranteed to never overlap with any other Fruit values.
  Pear = upstreamLibrary.getFruitValue("Pear"),
}

useFruit(FruitCustom.Pear);
```

However, this will throw a compiler error, because `FruitCustom` does not match `Fruit`. So, in my library, I have to type the `useFruit` function like this:

```
export function useFruit(fruit: Fruit | number) {}
```

Unfortunately, `Fruit | number` resolves to just `number`, so now I've lost type safety, which sucks!

What's the best way to handle this?

Additional discussion: We can't use [enum merging](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/typescript-enum-declaration-merging) to solve this problem because you can only do that with local enums. Because `Fruit` comes from a 3rd party library, TypeScript won't let you do that.

Other requirements: If the solution involves not using `enum`, then it is necessary to be able to iterate over the members of the enum, like you can with normal enums.

Comment: How does the "const object" approach actually work? Can you show an example? I don't see how users could merge the new values into it.

Comment: It almost seems like `Fruit` should be a nominal subtype of `number` that you have no knowledge or control over in the compiler.  But then apparently the compiler does know that `Fruit.Apple` is `0` and `Fruit.Banana` is `1`.  Does something go wrong if the compiler isn't aware of the literal values of these things?

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbADwBkCGAjCAbAPigF4oA7BAW1zigDIoBvKAfRYDNEUAhOTMgCYAuKFlx4oAXwDcAWABQCgRADGeTHGgqA9mQDOwKAHEIwAJLAIlMwO4gAcpkoQRGHPigQAHpcF6oBnBIZADmUAA+UADkUQQAFOriImL4AJQkRPDIaCmECgo6+oYAChAaJMamFlY2do7OcVGlGlGp0lAA9B2wXGhNZXCx+fLKahrQlNoCCHjQUVkoelFMClBQwZZw7Jgq0AvAegCymGAr8mtrzXAioJDa7FBXADSrUgqSCkA

Comment: Uh... please put the example in the question (unless the part of the question about const objects is not really relevant to the question, in which case maybe you should remove it).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does something go wrong". To be clear, the program will crash if you pass an invalid value to the upstream `useFruit`, so the goal of my library is trying to make working with it more type-safe.

Comment: I guess I'll remove the discussion on objects.

Comment: Your example doesn't have anything I'd call a "const object" in it (I doubt you mean the function)... instead it looks like you're doing namespace stuff which might have been something I'd suggest here.  Given that in that example the compiler has no idea that `Fruit.Apple` has the literal value `0` then I guess nothing does go wrong... the compiler doesn't need to be aware of the literal values of the enums.  But I don't know if you can confirm that or not if you don't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: if `useFruit` doesn't know that `FruitCustom` exists then it can't use that enum for anything. Are you wanting to pass in a custom enum to use? Like this? https://tsplay.dev/WzOl3w

Comment: I do not have a hard-requirement that the compiler knows the values of 0 or 1. However, I think that the compiler knowing the values is preferable for the UX/DX of my end-users, since it is nice to be able to see the values of "0" or "1" when they mouse over the enum members.

Comment: Well my thoughts here look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxYZKW); it could probably be modified to give those `0` and `1` types to the non-custom ones, but I don't know if this works for your use cases, especially the IDE-related stuff you deleted from the question.

Comment: @AlexWayne That's interesting, but it's too verbose to be very useful for my case. I don't want users to have to specify the type of the variable every single time they call a helper function, because they will be calling helper functions very, very frequently. I was hoping to have them "brand" their `FruitCustom` enum once at initialization, and then not have to do anything further.

Comment: @jcalz I like that solution a lot, as it doesn't seem too complicated and is relatively easy to read. However, I can't iterate over the enum now, right? That's also a requirement that I didn't include in the question.

Comment: I think you can iterate the namespace members like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMM3Vm).  Of course if you have a requirement then it should be included in the question; could you add that in?  Do you want me to write this up as an answer?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, you can iterate over namespace members. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a reasonable answer.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance; might not be until tomorrow

Comment: Also see the answer I posted below; I think that this might be preferable, since it has the property of the "vanilla" values are separated from the "custom" values, and you can choose to iterate over either one.

Comment: I don't get notified unless you @jcalz me.  If you're not likely to accept my answer I probably won't spend the time/effort writing one up; I probably spend longer on them than I should.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. I'm not sure yet which is preferable, since it seems like both have pros and cons.

Comment: "I don't get notified unless you @jcalz me" <-- this is still true

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution from mkantor in the TypeScript Discord.

Instead of using a local enum, end-users would use a local custom object like this:

```
export const asFruit = (n: number): Fruit => n as Fruit;

const FruitCustom = { 
  Pear: asFruit(90),
  Blueberry: asFruit(91),
  Raspberry: asFruit(92),
}

useFruit(FruitCustom.Pear);
```

Obviously, this has a lot of boilerplate, since you have to use `asFruit` for every single enum member. To get rid of the boilerplate, we can use something like:

```
const FruitCustomRaw = { 
  Pear: 90,
  Grape: 91,
  Blueberry: 92,
}

const turnIntoFruit = <K extends string>(fruits: Record<K, number>): Record<K, Fruit> => fruits as Record<K, Fruit>;

const FruitCustom = turnIntoFruit(FruitCustomRaw);
```